# Thunderbolt 3 to 144Hz monitor

Tags: display, compatibility, cable, thunderbolt

I'm planning to buy a Dell XPS 13'' 9300 laptop. It has 2 Thunderbolt 3 ports, and I really need it to work with a BenQ Zowie XL2411 144Hz monitor for CS:GO (2x HDMI, DVI-D, VGA). How is this possible? I know the monitor only supports 144 hz through the DVI-D. I'm trying to do research, but I'm so confused by all the different sorts and types of cables. Do I only need one cable, a docking station or is it even possible? If anyone could help me out with this, it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an active converter from DisplayPort to Dual-link (important!) DVI. Of course, this converter also has to support the desired display mode (1920x1080@144Hz).

Your laptop would not have a DisplayPort output but rather USB-C. Not only can it transport DisplayPort over Thunderbolt, it also supports DisplayPort Alt Mode, which is basically plain old DisplayPort, with a different connector (and some other stuff).

StarTech offers one such converter, called “USB-C to DVI Adapter - Dual-Link Connectivity - Active Conversion” (Product ID: CDP2DVIDP). However, it is expensive (~ US$ 145 when buying directly).

You could also buy a cheap USB-C-DisplayPort adapter (passive) and then buy another adapter from DisplayPort to DL-DVI (active). However, depending on the USB-C-DisplayPort adapter you may not get the full DisplayPort bandwidth (4 lanes).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer. I might just buy a new monitor. Then the best option would probably be a monitor which accepts a displayport, and then buy USB-C to Display port adapter.